# How do I perform a Left Outer Join in Linq?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join

I am new to Linq, and I need to convert this query to a left outer join between DocumentStores and Orders, as not all documents are related to an order:

```
    var documents=(from d in _dataContextOrders .DocumentStores 
                           join o in _dataContextOrders.Orders on d.OrderID equals o.ID
                           join t in _dataContextOrders .DocumentTypes on d.DocumentType equals t.DocTypeID
                       select new
                           {
                               d.ID,
                               o.PORef ,
                               t.DocTypeDescription,
                               d.Name,
                               d.ContentType
                           }).ToList();
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You may check this article i've written:  http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/A_11369-Joining-in-LINQ.html

Comment: Why do I see a new one of these questions every day?

Answer (score 1):

```
from a in dataContext.<tableA>
join _b in dataContext.<tableB> on a.id equals _b.aid into _b
from b in _b.DefaultIfEmpty()
select <whatyouwanttoselect>
```

b will be null, if the join on the ids fails